# Comparison between two tables using python script

Tags: python, mysql

I am having two tables

First table: having more data here putting condition like

```
select PROJ_No from INSProjectDataStaging where PROJ_NO>='7000-00'
(only this particular records will be present in second table)
```

Second table: needs to check the data whether those records are present in this table or not. Here I can fetch data from db but I need add one condition `if PROJ_NO<7000` invalid project along with the other valid project numbers 
here is my python code

```
cursor.execute(qstr):
    try:
        result=cursor.fetchall()
        col_names=[i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        for row in result:
            row_dict = dict(zip(col_names,row))
            new_row = list()
            for k,v in row_dict.iteritems():
                new_row.append(str(k)+"."+str(v))
            Databaserecords.append(new_row)
            for k.LOG_PROJ_NO in qstr:
                if k.LOG_PROJ_NO<'7000-00':
                    print "invalid project number existed"
    except Exception as e:
        print "problem in getting records from DatabaseTable with the query\n",qstr,"\nDetails:-",e

compare("select Activity_Code,PROJ_NO,LOG_PROJ_NO,LOG_DESC from table1 inner join table2 on table1.PROJ_NO=table2.LOG_PROJ_NO")
```

But output showing as invalid project number existed for all records, I require output like if invalid project number exists along with other valid records it has to show invalid record in extra column
Please help on this issue

Comment: k.LOG_PROJ_NO<'7000-00' it's not a proper comparison.. need more clarity on your question

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. For this, a sample data set of both tables, and the desired output would greatly help understand what you are trying to do.  Remember, we do not know your context.